# Fetching data from database based on current time PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, postgresql, relational-database

So I am fetching data from my PostgreSQL data by executing a query in my Index.php. This query fetches the name of the bus station name along with the corresponding time it will be arriving. What I want my application to do is fetch times for a specific bus station selected based on the current time.

My query is the following:

```
   $query = " SELECT busname, bustime
              From busses
             where name = '$name' and time ='$time' LIMIT 5";
```

Would I need to do something in my query to achieve this or in my database ?

Comment: $query = " SELECT busname, bustime
              From busses
             where name = '$name' and time <= NOW() LIMIT 5";

Comment: That seems to bring up an error : 

Query failed: ERROR: operator does not exist: time with time zone >= timestamp with time zone LINE 4: ...mesDyke' and dt2.name = 'CitySquare' and dt1.time >= NOW() a... ^ HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

 @NIRANJANS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are basing it of current time you definitely don't want time='$time' as this will only ring true if you happen to be querying at the exact time down to the millisecond.

Presuming you are wanting to get all (or closest) times for a bus station based on current time then try:

```
$query = " SELECT busname, bustime
           From busses
           WHERE name = '$name' 
           AND time >= '$time'  
           ORDER BY time ASC 
           LIMIT 5";
```

This will give you all times after current time and then ordering by ASC will give the nearest time first, limiting 5 then returns only the next 5 bus times.

Comment: I have tried that but It wont fetch the data based on the current time. My $time variable is $time = $_POST['time'];// Time. Where I am supposed to be making a change @Matt

Comment: @bronxdeveloper How are you posting the time? are you using DateTime? e.g. `$time = new DateTime();` then posting it?

Comment: my time is $time = $_POST['time'];// What the user sends as input. Should I change it to $time = new DateTime(); ? @Matt